# Is there a one liner or more efficient way to get this done?

Tags: ruby

Given a hash, for example:

```
hash = { "fish" => 2, "cat" => 3, "dog" => 1 }
```

I need to get:

1. A comma separated string for all the values, E.g. "2,3,1"
2. An integer that hold the total sum of the values, E.g. 6

My current code:

```
value_string = hash.map { |k,v| "#{v}"}.join(',')
sum = 0
hash.map { |k,v| sum += v}
```

Comment: Do you really need one liner solution for two problems?  Both on its own can be one liner

Comment: You can always turn any Ruby code into a one-liner by replacing the linebreaks with semicolons: `value_string = hash.map { |k,v| "#{v}"}.join(','); sum = 0; hash.map { |k,v| sum += v}` Voila! One line, just as you asked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
hash.values.join(",") # => "2,3,1"
hash.values.inject(:+) # => 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to compute both the values in single iteration (some sort of ***one liner***)

```
r1,r2 = hash.reduce([nil, 0]){|m,(_,v)| [[m[0], v.to_s].compact.join(","),m[-1]+v]}
#=> ["2,3,1", 6]
```